# Get distinct values for a string in a cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like that:

[image]

I want to get the distinct sections, in fact the distinct first string from the section colume. I tried advanced filters however, this only gives me the whole string. Is there a excel formula to check the columes just for the first string?(Like here: `bla, blub, bla1, bla2, blue`)

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, add a new column with:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2))
```

that will give you the list of first words; after that you can use filters.